# Create new data frame with the name from loop number

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I tried to create the loop in python. The code can be seen below.

```
df=pd.DataFrame.copy(mef_list)
form=['','_M3','_M6','_M9','_M12','_LN','_C']
for i in range(0, len(form)):
    df=pd.DataFrame.copy(mef_list)
    df['Variable_new']=df['Variable']+str(form[i])
```

When I run the code, the result is only from the last loop, which is `variable+'_C'` I think it is because the data frame (df) is always replaced when the new loop start. In order to avoid the issue, I would think that if the data frame (df) could be renamed by plus the number of loop, the problem would be solved.

I used str function and hope to get `df0`, `df1`, ...,`df6` but it doesn't work with the data frame name. Please suggest me how to change the name of data frame by add number of loop and also I still open for any alternative way.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post codes as images.

Comment: @Nouman Thanks, revised

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a pythonic thing to do, have you thought about instead creating a list of dataframes?

```
df=pd.DataFrame.copy(mef_list)
form=['','_M3','_M6','_M9','_M12','_LN','_C']
list_of_df = list()
for i in range(0, len(form)):
    df=pd.DataFrame.copy(mef_list)
    df['Variable_new']=df['Variable']+str(form[i])
    list_of_df.append(df)
```

Then you can access '`df0`' as `list_of_df[0]`

You also don't need to iterate through a range, you can just loop through the form list itself:

```
form=['','_M3','_M6','_M9','_M12','_LN','_C']
list_of_df = list()
for i in form:
    df=pd.DataFrame.copy(mef_list)
    df['Variable_new']=df['Variable']+str(i) ## You can remove str() if everything in form is already a string
    list_of_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mef_list = ["UR", "CPI", "CEI", "Farm", "PCI", "durable", "C_CVM"]
form = ['', '_M3', '_M6', '_M9', '_M12', '_LN', '_C']
Variable_new = []
foo = 0
for variable in form:
     Variable_new.append(mef_list[foo]+variable)
     foo += 1
print(Variable_new)
```

Comment: I need in terms of data frame because there are some information that have to remain even the name are changed

Comment: @SasiwutChaiyadecha I've modified the code, hope it help you out.